# Use global npm or not

Tags: javascript, node.js, symfony

When and why I have to use -g when install new module?

I use symfony and i have create Bundle for node and install node_modules inside bundle with (for example cd ../mybundle, then)

```
npm install felixge/node-mysql
```

when and Why I have to do something link

```
npm install -g felixge/node-mysql
```

thanks

Comment: The difference is documented in [npm-folders(5)](https://npmjs.org/doc/files/npm-folders.html). "*Install it **locally** if you're going to require() it. Install it **globally** if you're going to run it on the command line. If you need both, then install it in both places, or use `npm link`.*"

Answer (score 3):

From http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/

In general, the rule of thumb is:

If you’re installing something that you want to use in your program, using require('whatever'), then install it locally, at the root of your project.

If you’re installing something that you want to use in your shell, on the command line or something, install it globally, so that its binaries end up in your PATH environment variable.

Comment: `mysql = require('mysql')
fb = require('./bc_modules/facebook')`

in this case mysql is global and fb is local ?

Comment: @user3093439 No. You can't (or at least shouldn't be able to) `require()` globally installed modules. `mysql` would be locally installed while `facebook` is just relative to the current module.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski When i use `required`, i use the locally modules ? without `required` use globally installed modules?
if you use modules locally is not necessary to write `var sugar = require('./node_modules/sugar')` but I can use `var sugar = require('sugar')` because `./node_modules` it's default?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski is right. `require()` should be used for locally installed modules. Globally installed modules should be called from the cmd line when needed. And `./node_modules` is the default install path for locally installed packages so you can just call `var sugar = require('sugar')`.

Comment: @user3093439 Yeah. Though, there's still a bit more to it. The rules that `require()` follows are [documented in Modules](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html). For `require('sugar')`, it'll expect `sugar` to either be a [core module](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_core_modules) or [will crawl parent directories looking for `node_modules/sugar`](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders). NPM's local install mode then places modules into a `node_modules` directory for `require()` to be able to find.

Answer (score 2):

The `-g` flag installs packages on your user profile whereas not having this puts it in your current folder. The difference is the scope of the package.